# Concatenating In PHP

Tags: php

What is the proper way to write the following code?

```
echo '<img src="'images/.$row['picture']. '"/>';
```

I want to display an image from the database.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the question correctly,

```
<?php
echo '<img src="/images/' . $row['picture'] . '"/>';
?>
```

or

```
<?php
echo "<img src='/images/" . $row['picture'] . "'/>";
?>
```

Comment: I would like to comment that concatenate html with data from sources which may be not controlled by you is not a good practice. In this case it's good to escape the data with `htmlspecialchars` function to prevent XSS atacks. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet it's a good resource about XSS

Answer (score 2):

You can use vprintf function: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.vprintf.php

```
vprintf('<img src="images/%s"/>', $row['picture']);
```

Or this:

```
echo "<img src=\"{$row['picture']}\" />";
```

Don't forget to escape html characters: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

```
$row['picture'] = htmlspecialchars($row['picture'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo  '<img src="images/'.$row['picture'].'" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
echo "<img src=images/".$row['picture']."/>";
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this output: <img src=images/[variable]>
img tags need to be <img src="/images/[variable]"/>

Answer (score 0):

```
    echo '<img src=images/'.$row['picture'].'>';
```

Comment: Wouldn't this output: <img src=images/[variable]>
img tags need to be <img src="/images/[variable]"/>